# how to add a RecyclerView to LinearLayout ( height issue )

Tags: java, android, height, android-recyclerview

I want to add a recyclerview with custom adapter , but when i add it to a LinearLayout it doesn't show any item , but when i set height on 500 ( for example ) I can see the items , but it's not working on WRAP_CONTENT or MATCH_PARENT , so what should i do ? how can i set the height automatic?
sorry for my English

code :

```
    adapterCustom = new AdapterCustom(customArrayList);
LinearLayout recyclerLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(currentActivity).inflate(R.layout.recycler_layout, null);
RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) recyclerLayout.findViewById(R.id.mainRecycler);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(currentActivity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recycler.setAdapter(adapterCustom);
recycler.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
recyclerLyt.addView(recyclerLayout);
```

**I forgot to say , my recyclerview is Horizontal**

Comment: What is the linearLayout's height? Is linearLayout in some other layout?

Answer (score 0):

Please update version of the library in gradle file :

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
Prior to this recylerviews needed either a fixed height on height set to match_parent.

Comment: unfortunately i can't download API or SDK or any tools  , because i live in iran and we don't have access to the server ....